# Building a .Jar file with Android.mk

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, android.mk

Trying to produce a .jar archive from java files in my folder "java" which is in the same directory as my Android.mk build file. I know the Android.mk file is being run, but it is not producing a .jar

This is what i have so far:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := Test
Test:libs/Test.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := owner
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under,java)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TEST-JAR
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := Test
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Ive also tried:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under,java)
LOCAL_MODULE := TEST-JAR
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libTest
include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libTest:libs/Test.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := Test:libs/Test.jar
include $(BUILD_HOST_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Test-JAR
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java)
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += Test 
include $(BUILD_HOST_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

this will build a host java library Test-JAR.jar

Answer (score -1):

You cannot produce JAR files from *Android.mk*.

Android NDK builds are supposed to be invoked from Gradle build scripts, which are then responsible for producing jar, aar, apk, depending on the configuration options.

Have a look at older Android NDK samples with ndk-build.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/other-builds/ndkbuild

Comment: In fact, you can do it if you build Android yourself (a custom ROM for example).